# Is encouraging the use of frameworks/libraries as an answer, acceptable?

Tags: discussion, answers

So, let's say someone has a problem with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, and they are solving it with **pure** HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, either because they don't know better, they want to get a better grasp of the language/script/markup, or are plain masochists that want hundreds of lines of code for a button.

Is it a mildly-acceptable answer, to encourage them to use X framework/library (say for responsive design, or something like jQuery, express...) ***along with a demonstration on how their problem would/can be solved using what we recommended***, or should it be preserved in a comment?

Comment: Provided **you are actually solving the stated problem** it's fine. But an bare answer of, for instance, *"Bootstrap can do this"* is the definition of a poor answer.

Comment: Frankly though I see no reason to recommend Frameworks or Libraries as a matter of course. I'd rather solve the problems with *their* code than re-write the thing just to use an external resource.

Comment: The way I see it: it's advice, not an answer. So if you want to give advice, that is best reserved for a footnote in a proper answer. Comments are not really a good platform for it as you can't properly format your advice and any code you may want to add to it. I would still be careful though, giving advice can invite others to do the same and promote their favorite tools. If there are dozens of popular frameworks that can get it done, I'd just not do it.